# show a trsansparent png image on a web page

Tags: html, css, image

I have to show a transparent png image with html code. I don't have to show transparent sections of the image on the page.

```
<div class="col-lg-3" style="background-color:grey">
<img src="img/brand.png" width="100" height="100" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>
</div>
```

I would to show only non-transparent sections of the image and show background of main div instead transparent sections.  Means I want to hide transparent sections of the image.

Comment: i see no problem there if your png is really transparent at some points.

Comment: idem, no trouble seen here, if png is clearly transparent, the bg color should be seen where png is translucide.

Comment: Cant you just chop the image in gimp or photoshop? Filesize will decrease alot when you get rid of the transparent parts of your page and thus will make it load faster on slow internet connections.

Otherwise you could put the png as the background image of your div and make it background-position: center center; but that would imply that the transparent areas are exacly on the outsides.

There is no nice way to do this AFAIK.

Comment: It's un*clear* what you're asking. Teehee.

Comment: Transparent PNGs are transparent, so shown or not, you don't see them (at least not those pixels that are transparent. Only exception is when your browser doesn't support the transparency feature of PNG image (Internet Explorer 6 and 7), but if you use one of those browsers, you really need to upgrade.